Generalized Eigenvalue Problem with Kronecker Products
It is known for matrices $A,B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, and $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $B$, we have every eigenvalue of $A\otimes B$ is a product of eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$, counting multiplicities.
Let $C,D,E,F\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and let us assume that $(C\otimes D)$ is symmetric positive semi definite, and $(E\otimes F)$ is symmetric positive definite. Is there a similar idea for the generalized eigenvalue problem: $(C\otimes D) x = \omega (E\otimes F) x?$
More succinctly, are the eigenvalues $\omega$ from the generalized problem related to the eigenvalues of $C,D,E,F$?
Maybe $\omega$ is the product of eigenvalues from $C x = r E x$ and $D x = s F x$?

If $E$ and $F$ are invertible, this can be reduced to finding the solutions to the eigenvalue problem $(E^{-1}C) \otimes (F^{-1}D) x = \omega x$, so your conjecture is correct in that case
